# Does @everywhere not load a function on the master?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I made a module with an if condition on the number of cores. If the number of cores is more than 1 the route is parallel; otherwise, it goes the serial route as seen in the code below

```
module mymodule

import Pkg

using Distributed

if nworkers() > 1
    @everywhere using Pkg
    @everywhere Pkg.activate(".")
    @everywhere Pkg.instantiate()
    @everywhere using CSV
    @everywhere include("src/myfuncs.jl")

    function func()
        df=CSV.read(file);
        .......
    end

else
    using Pkg
    Pkg.activate(".")
    Pkg.instantiate()
    using CSV
    include("src/myfuncs.jl")
    function func()
        df=CSV.read(file);
        .......
    end
end
end #mymodule
```

1) When I instantiate a Julia session, e.g., `julia -p 8` I get an error saying `ERROR: UndefVarError: CSV not defined`. On the other hand, when a session is instantiated simply as `julia` there is no error. The Project.toml & Master.toml files are one level higher than `src`. Do I have to load on the master before using `@everyone`, like

```
include("src/myfuncs.jl")
@everywhere include("src/myfuncs.jl")
```

2) Moreover, I find that when the program goes the serial route it can't find the `myfunc.jl` file because it is already in the `src` folder (looks for `src/src/myfunc.jl`), this behavior is confusing me.

Can someone share their thoughts here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@everywhere` *does* execute on all workers *and* the master. However:

1. Sometimes, if you have bad luck and the module that you are importing is not compiled, a race condition can occur (not always reproducible but reported by several users on StackOverflow), hence, the best bet is to always write the code like this (note that if your cluster is distributed across many servers this might not be enough):

   ```
   using Distributed
   @everywhere using Distributed
   using CSV
   @everywhere using CSV
   ```
2. Modify your code to run `using` *before* `Pkg.activate`
3. I am not sure what you want to achieve by `@everywhere Pkg.instantiate()` but for sure what you are doing now this can not be good (you must make sure that it is not run in more than one copy for a cluster node)
4. Finally, there is no need to separate your code depending on the number of workers - see the safe pattern in point (1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: your suggestions were helpful. However, this question is still pestering me.  `include("myfuncs.jl");
@everywhere include("src/myfuncs.jl")` - Only doing so works, what explains this behavior?

Comment: It is exactly the same compilation race issue. You want to have compiled code first and than use it. In your question you have also used different location for `myfuncs.jl` and `src/myfuncs.jl` - normally it should not be case unless you perform a custom launch of slave processes or some processes change their home folder location (e.g. via the `cd` function)

Comment: I have not used different location for `myfuncs.jl` and `src/myfuncs.jl`. I have been "forced" to use it because as you have mentioned it looks some processes are changing their home folder location (I don't understand why this is happening?)

Comment: Also, your suggestion to not separate code depending on the number of workers has been implemented and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Regarding folders - I have never observed them changing unless you execute `cd` on your master process before starting the slave processes.